# how to extract json response data in jmeter using regular expression extractor?

Tags: regex, json, jmeter

I am just trying to extract json response data using jmeter but not able to do so.
I am getting something like `{"authorizationToken":"abcdef"}`.
I am trying to get `authorizationToken` but not able to get this.

Can anyone help me getting this working?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is `authorizationToken` appearance unique in response (does it appear only once)?

If it does you may simply use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) added to the HTTP Request which returns json response, with regex like following:

`HTTP Request
    Regular Expression Extractor
    Reference Name: authToken
    Regular Expression: "authorizationToken":"(.+?)"
    Template: $1$
    Match No.: 1`

and refer further extracted value as `${authToken}`.

---

But if your case is more complicated and there several appearances of `authorizationToken` in json response and you have to extract concrete one you may use e.g. [BeanShell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) / [BSF PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BSF_PostProcessor) added to the same HTTP Request to extract value with beanshell code + [json processing library](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven/com.metaparadigm/jars/json-rpc-1.0.jar).

If not - the first solution above should help.

---

**UPDATE:**

At the moment the most comfortable way to process JSON responses seems to be custom [JSON utils](https://github.com/ATLANTBH/jmeter-components/) for jmeter (JSON Path Assertion, JSON Path Extractor, JSON Formatter) which are also part of [Jmeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ExtrasWithLibsSet/).

In this particular case you can use [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/).

Comment: Thanks Alies.Actually i have defined the same variable "AUTHTOKEN" in user defined variables.That was causing error.I have removed it and it just works fine.