# Extracting JSON Response using regular expression extractor in Jmeter

Tags: regex, json, jmeter

I want to extract the key value from the JSON response received for a login web service and pass that key value to all other subsequent services.

Note: This key value is dynamic.

The JSON response looks like this:

```
{
 "key":"jwtjWgwnqIVapQeDh47rkFaKV6E",
 "username":"Tester",
 "password":"xyz",
 "servername":"123.45.6.789",
 "mailpath":"mail/tmail5.nsf",
 "pin":"xxxx",
 "defaultAttachments":"OFF",
 "sendMailsFor":"W-1",
 "serverTime":"10/09/2012 20:02:57"
}
```

Please help me in writing the reqular expression to extract the same and to pass that key value to all other next web services.

Please let me know what should I write in the fields "Reference Name:", "Regular Expression:", "Template:", "Match No.:" and how to declare the "Reference Name" in the next web services.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If `key` appearance is unique in response you may simply use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) added to the HTTP Request which returns json response, with regex like following:

`HTTP Request
    Regular Expression Extractor
    Reference Name: authKey
    Regular Expression: "key":"(.+?)"
    Template: $1$
    Match No.: 1`

and refer extracted value as `${authKey}` in all the further requests/samplers across your test.

As well you can look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416300/how-to-extract-json-response-data-in-jmeter-using-regular-expression-extractor) for the same situation.
And please don't be lazy in future to look first a bit around: it can appear that answer to your question already exists here.

Comment: Observed a space is added in the response data after using this regular expression                                               POST data: {"data":"NA,,-,,{\"list\":\"84726F0E98A79DA265257A8A001F3C4B \", \"key\":\"QE0tENEENbtUVXybB0-SVgSAEfI \",\"folder\":\"$Inbox\"}"}                                           Can you please explain me why this extra space is added in response data after the extracted key value.