# Using Extracted JSON Value in Another JMeter Thread

Tags: jmeter

First, let me preface this question that I've only been using JMeter for 36 hours.

I've been able to successfully create a thread that performs a POST (json body)  to generate a new record.

```
{  
   "id":1257697771,
   "displayName":"TERM2",
   "functionName":"f_1257697771",
   "displayableSourceExpression":"TRUE",
   "typeId":200,
   "groupId":300,
   "clobObjId":1257697772,
   "typeCode":5,
   ..........
}
```

I need to take the new record's ID (1257697771) value returned in order to perform updates, get by ID, delete, etc. on this record in other threads.

After much reading, I've created a Regular Expression Extractor where:

- *Apply to*: Main Sample Only
- *Field to Check*: Body as Document
- *Reference Name*: **newRecord**
- *Regular Expression*: "id":(.+?)\,"displayName"
- *Template*: $1$
- *Match No*: 1
- *Default Value*: NONE

At this point, I'm not sure if my Regular Expression is formatted correctly where (.+?) is valid.

Also, I'm confused if I can either just specify the new reference (**newRecord**) in another thread's HTTP request's Parameters or use a BeanShell Post-Processor, or a Response Assertion, etc....

There a lot of answers for the same function of "Passing". **Not being a programmer**, I've tried to follow the discussion "[how to extract json response data in jmeter using regular expression extractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416300/how-to-extract-json-response-data-in-jmeter-using-regular-expression-extractor)", but I'm still not clear.

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Regexp is better to be: "id":(\d+?),
newRecord you can use in every another sampers and beanshells using ${newRecord}. In beanshel is also you can get value using String s = vars.get("newRecord");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JMeter Variables are local to Thread Group, you need to convert your variable to JMeter Property.

Use:

1. [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function in the Thread Group where you define your `newRecord` variable like:

   ```
    ${__setProperty(newRecord,${newRecord},)}
   ```
2. [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function to access property value like:

   ```
   ${__P(newRecord,)}
   ```

[image: Passing variable between thread groups]

See [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) article for more detailed explanation.

Also be aware of the [Function Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) as it looks like JMeter functions syntax was developed by aliens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually watched BlazeMeter videos and read a lot of their posts to get this far. I feel like I'm so close, but am missing something.

For the __setProperty(), create a BeanShell Assertion in the "generating" thread and put the function in the Script leaving the Parameters and Script File fields null. Is this correct?

In the 2nd thread's HTTP Request, the path is 
http://devsrf5145:18100/dvlp/dynamic/rwcm/2002/crud/Expression/

I need to append this path with the variable generated in the 1st thread. So do I place the "${__P(newRecord,)}" in the Send Parameters?

Comment: 1. You can use `__setProperty()` function anywhere, not necessarily in the assertion. 2. If you need to add it to path - `__P()` function directly to the path

Answer (score 4):

To pass a value between threads you need to use the [jmeter property](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) function.

In a jsr223 postprocessor using groovy the code to get the value is as follows:

```
 def userProperty = props.get('propertyToGet')
vars.put('userProperty', String.valueOf(userProperty))
```

You would then access the variable in your thread using:

```
${userProperty}
```

Or you can use shorthand directly:

```
${__P('propertyToGet')}
```

Variables in jmeter are thread specific.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Trying to figure out what you're saying now. I'm still too new to this to know exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. I was able to resolve it with your help!

In the first thread:

- set the Reg Expression Extractor *Regular Expression* = "id":(.+?)\,"displayName"
- added a Bean Assertion where *Parameters* = ${__setProperty(newRecord,${newRecord},)}

In the second thread:

- appended the Path url with ${__P(newRecord,)}

Executing the first thread (POST) resulted an new record with a unique ID. (1257698108)

Executing the 2nd thread (GET) shows

`GET http://server/.../.../.../.../1257698108`

And returns the exact data generated in the first thread.

Thanks everyone for your help!